# horizontally centre position fixed element

Tags: html, css

I have a notification system I am building in jquery and I am trying to horizontally center the notification's container div.

I've tried `left:50%;`, `margin:0 auto;`, and `left:50%; and right:50%;' none of which work.

So I resorted to estimating the centre  with something like `left:40%;`, but that will only work for one of a small range of viewports and I need this to work in as many viewports as possible.

So I decided to use media-queries to give different `left` values based on the viewport width.
However, upon testing, I noticed even in small viewports, the media query is not working and it is taking the styling on the largest breakpoint.

Why is that? And how can I properly horizontally centre the notification properly is as many viewports as possible.

Here is a JS Fiddle with the styling and the code to trigger the notification, just click anywhere to trigger the notification: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6TUr/

And here is the page where I am trying to get this all to work, click anywhere in the grey background ot trigger the notification: http://goo.gl/Dalkqh

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me how to properly figure out how to properly centre the notification horizontally in all viewports.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.style.marginLeft = -element.offsetWidth/2+'px';
```

A more flexible method to do.

Unable to show the result based on your JS Fiddle. You are not providing the original script...sorry I can't read that.

Comment: when I try to add the code to the htmlElement, it says it is undefined and then the whole script doesn't work. Here is all the script in a more readable format. The part where I try what you recommend is at line 28: https://gist.github.com/theirf/422f1c7e903b3074877b

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out a way to get the element. But now it is saying it's .offsetWidth is undefined. `$('.notification').css('marginLeft', -$(this).offsetWidth/2);
alert($('.notification').offsetWidth);` The alert alerts undefined.

Comment: In JQuery it should be $(this).outerWidth()

Comment: It is just the way to do it. element means a HTMLElement object. Don't confuse about them.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense. I got it working, well, there are no errors. But the notification is still floated left / left-aligned and not centred horizontally. Here is my code, your suggestion is on line 58: https://gist.github.com/theirf/b7184fe8568a34a7b41d

Here is the page: http://goo.gl/ZC8ZlN, the code is in jquery.notifications.js

Comment: It seems like you have not correctly set css left property. Are you sure to set position to 'fixed' or 'absolute' and left to '50%'?

Comment: yes, I believe I have. But I figured out the solution with `left:50%;` and `marginLeft:-50% of the width;` Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one trick that I can suggest you to use: rely on CSS 2D transform. It is [supported in around 81% of web users](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d), so it is worth trying.

What this trick does it that it still sets the notification message 50% across the width of the page (which is of course, visually off). We then nudge the element back to the true center by translating it by 50% of its own calculated width.

```
.notification-board.center{
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6TUr/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a wrapper then center the wrapper or you can center it using the width:

Wrapper:

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='fixed'>Hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

**Or:**

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='fixed'>Hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    width: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

Comment: When I add your first option of the wrapper and the styling to the wrapper, the notification doesn't show at all anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6TUr/2/

Comment: This is because for some reason the notification has `style='display: none'` @gomangomango

Comment: Do you have any idea where that is coming from? I can't find from where?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the top,left,right,bottom attributes you need to set you element position to either relative or absolute.

I think in your case you may want to use absolute.
You might need to also set z-index.